# Vue: change the way of parsing elements of templates and keep self closed tags

Tags: html, vuejs3

I have a MPA Vue app with following config:

```
pages: {
    'index': {
        entry: vueWorkDirPath + '/page/public/home/main.js',
        template: vueWorkDirPath + '/template/default.html',
        title: 'Home',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    'test': {
        ....
    }
}
```

The MPA config is all working fine, however in my template file (default.html) I have a reference to a custom style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/style/sheet/custom.css" />
```

Note the self closing tag there.

However, after I run npm run build, Vue builds the index file and above element is changed to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/style/sheet/custom.css">
```

Note the self-closing tag was removed (from /> to >).

I purposely used the self closing tag (/>) because the index file is processed by another framework (which I must use). This framework need old style XHTML rendering, and throws errors if the link element has no self closed tag. I guess Vue wants to force the build to use strictly compatible HTML5 elements. However the HTML5 standard itself allows closing tags...

I also noticed that in the index file, other things are changed. I have a hidden attribute in an anchor element like this:

```
<a href="member" hidden="#{userSession.loggedIn ? 'hidden' : ''}" class="nav-link topBottomSlideIn">Login</a>
```

After npm run build it shows like this:

```
<a href="member" hidden class="nav-link topBottomSlideIn">Login</a>
```

Here also Vue has some kind of need to rewrite the hidden element to follow HTML5 standards.

I also use a custom element:

```
<h:commandLink value="Logout" actionListener="#{userSession.logOut}" styleClass="nav-link topBottomSlideIn" />
```

And it is changed to:

```
<h:commandlink value="Logout" actionListener="#{userSession.logOut}" styleClass="nav-link topBottomSlideIn" >
```

Note here again the removal of the self closed tag and more importantly: in 'h:commandLink' the upper case 'L' was changed to lower case 'l'! Now, the framework cannot render it anymore unfortunately.

So, here some questions:

1. Is there a way to change this behaviour of Vue? I understands the need for sticking to strict HTML5 compatibilty, but browsers can render HTML5 elements with self closed tags anyway...
2. If not possible, is there a way to do some post processing and execute some replace functinality so I still can replace /> by >, or h:commandlink by h:commandLink?
3. If above is not possible, any other tools who could achieve this? I prefer to fully stick to Vue functionality, but maybe there is some HTML related formatter which I might use in my IDE? Or something else?

Btw I am using the just released Vue.js 3.0.2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** There's one option that needs enabling on `production` build (at least up to Vue 3.0.2):

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'index': {
      minify: {
        // your other options go here

        keepClosingSlash: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that by default, this `minify` option is disabled (set to `false`); therefore, by setting it to an object, we'll have to specify the options for the minifer. On `production` build, Vue uses its own minification settings, one of which is `collapseWhitespace`. Please review all the configurable [options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) and pick ones that suit your requirement.

#### How & Why

Under the hood, Vue CLI [minifies](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#minification) HTML and static assets with `html-minifier`, and to keep the trailing slash on self-closing tags, this option ([`keepClosingSlash`](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)) needs to be enabled—because it defaults to `false`. However, this will not work with resource hints (`preload`/`prefetch`) and manifest/icon links—without additional configurations.

BTW, before we get to the other configs, you might have noticed this other option called `xhtml`, and despite the description that says:

> If `true` render the link tags as self-closing (XHTML compliant)

...and the fact that it also defaults to `false`, you might think that this will work by simply enabling it, but it unfortunately won't. This option only applies to static assets and not the resource-hinted ones.

So, here's how to fix it: In addition to the `keepClosingSlash` option being enabled, we'll need to [tap](https://github.com/webpack/tapable/tree/master) into this particular hook called [`alterAssetTags`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#alterassettags-hook) and this special attribute named `selfClosingTag` on the individual tags (the target/self-closing elements that need these trailing slashes appended on them).

(This should probably be better off filed as an issue on the GitHub page, because it really should work for all types of asset).

But anyway. The easiest way to configure the said option would be to...

#### Create a custom plugin

```js
const voidTags = ['area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr'];

class HtmlTagSelfCloser {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(this.constructor.name, compilation => {
      compilation.hooks.htmlWebpackPluginAlterAssetTags.tap(
        this.constructor.name,

        htmlPluginData => {
          htmlPluginData.head
            .filter(tag => voidTags.includes(tag.tagName))
            .forEach(tag => {
              tag.selfClosingTag = true;

              // OR, if you use the `xhtml` option (see the notes down below):
              // option tag.voidTag = true;
            });

          return htmlPluginData;
        }
      )
    });
  }
}
```

I call it `HtmlTagSelfCloser`, but feel free to name it whatever you like. We will add this plugin with [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) later as you read on.

In case you're wondering, `voidTags` here is actually [backported](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/0928c3cbfbd13d5bd43a8a8ded330fb4e5f6a4fc/lib/html-tags.js#L20) from the most recent (ATTOW) version of the plugin that stands for all html tag elements which must not contain `innerHTML`.

**Note**: See [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/e2c6990e94b298ff66bcd885c9a03a78221479f6/index.js#L629) for how these attributes work internally during compilation.

Lastly and most importantly, add the plugin into the mix (and put everything together):

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'index': {
      minify: {
        // your other options go here

        keepClosingSlash: true
      }
    }
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html-webpack-self-closer')
      .use(HtmlTagSelfCloser)
      .after('prefetch-index');
  }
}
```

This example assumes you are building the app in multi-page mode, with only one page (named "index") specified on the [`pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) object.

Please note that the ordering is important, and we need this plugin to go right **after** `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `PreloadPlugin`. To see how the ordering goes, run:

```sh
vue inspect --plugins
```

And that should get you something along these lines:

```js
[
  'vue-loader',
  'feature-flags',       
  'define',
  'case-sensitive-paths',
  'friendly-errors',

  'html-index',
  'preload-index',
  'prefetch-index',
  'html-webpack-self-closer',

  'copy',
  'fork-ts-checker'
]
```

As you can see, our custom plugin is added after `html-index` (`HtmlWebpackPlugin`) and the other resource-hint helper plugins (preload and prefetch).

⚠️ Note that we'll only need to add it **once**, even if you have multiple pages.

And voila, those should do the trick. :-)

---

My versions:

- Vue 3.0.2
- @vue/cli 4.5.7

Comment: It works for closing the tags now, but now it doesn't minify html files anymore at npm run build... :-( Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @onderbewustzijn Did you review all the configurable [options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)? By default, the `minify` option is not enabled, so by setting it to an object, we'll have to specify the options for the minifer. This particular option `collapseWhitespace` could be one of them.

Comment: Actually, that did it for me. Please try and enable this `collapseWhitespace` along with the `keepClosingSlash`. I'll edit the answer and add this note.

Comment: Btw tried your html HtmlTagSelfCloser with success. Just one small remark. The .after('prefetch-index') part should be altered to .after('prefetch-<page name>') where <page name> is the value in the pages element of the vue config. Also, what i tested, is that you can change multiple after's. Like: .after('prefetch-index').after('prefetch-product'). Anyway, thanks again for all the solutions!

Comment: @onderbewustzijn You're right. I edited the answer to clarify that part. Thanks!